# Can jetty have an infinite websocket timeout

Tags: java, websocket, timeout, jetty

I am using jetty to set up multiple servers with one proxy that then talks to a client.
The servers should be able to be connected for an infinite amount of time without stopping.
But whenever a test it after a little bit of time of inactivity the servers throw a read-timeout exception:

```
Session: localhost/127.0.0.1:8884
caused:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout on Read
Connection closed: Session: localhost/127.0.0.1:8884
caused:java.io.EOFException: Connection has been closed locally
```

I am not setting a timeout time because I assumed that no time would assume forever.
Is there a way to set it for forever?

Comment: Set an arbitrarily high timeout?

Comment: Why? It's a bad idea. Sockets that have been open for very long periods without activity are a waste of resources and a potential vector for a denial-of-service attack.

Comment: By default sockets hang indefinately unless stated otherwise. However being a good citizen, I would assume jetty to override this odd default with something usable. But resetting it to 0 will probably do the trick.

Comment: The sockets that I don't want to expire are internal facing.  And only connect to servers I control.  The public facing sockets do expire.  I was trying to make the servers really simple but I can see that was not a possibility.  I changed it so that if there is a message sent after it expires then it will attempt to reconnect them.  It is a lot more complicated but it does not require an infinite socket